How to Calculate the Slope of a Line Between Two Points in a Rotated Coordinate System? (Simple Math Problem)
Using Mediapipe, I can obtain the coordinates of points on a person's face through the webcam. I record these coordinates by considering the point at index 8 on the face (the middle point between the two eyebrows) as the origin. However, when the person turns their face, the coordinate plane also rotates accordingly. For instance, when the person’s face is directly facing the camera, the coordinate plane and the line between two points on the face look like this:
https://i.sstatic.net/3KsRBvpl.png
When the person turns their head, the coordinate plane and the line between two points on the face change as follows:
https://i.sstatic.net/cWR4JN5g.png
As you can see, when the person turns their head, the slope of the line between the two points on their face changes because this slope is calculated according to the non-rotated coordinate system. Here is my code:
def calculate_2D_slope(self, point1, point2):
    if point1 and point2:
        origin_point_no_8 = next((point for point in self.origin_points_coordinates if point["index"] == 8), None)
        origin_point_no_9 = next((point for point in self.origin_points_coordinates if point["index"] == 9), None)
        if origin_point_no_8["x"] == 0 and origin_point_no_8["y"] == 0 and origin_point_no_8["z"] == 0:
            origin_slope = (origin_point_no_9["y"] / origin_point_no_8["y"]) / (origin_point_no_9["x"] / origin_point_no_8["x"])
        else:
            print("Origin point 8 is not zero.")
            return None
        x1, y1 = point1["x"], point1["y"]
        x2, y2 = point2["x"], point2["y"]
        slope = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - origin_slope

In this code, origin_point_no_8 is the point at index 8 on the face (the middle point between the two eyebrows) and is considered as the origin. origin_point_no_9 is used to calculate the slope of the line between the origin point and the point at index 9 to determine the rotation of the coordinate system when the person turns their head. After calculating the slope of the line between points 8 and 9, I compute the slope of the line between the two points on the face and perform the operation slope = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - origin_slope.
The problem is that I am unsure how to process the difference between the coordinate system’s slope and the slope of the line between the two points on the face. How should I handle the slope between two points on a rotated face as if the rotated coordinate system were a normal coordinate system? If this sentence is unclear:
https://i.sstatic.net/9QwD5jAK.png
I want to calculate the two points on the face as shown above. Should I subtract, add, or perform some other operation with the slope of the rotated coordinate system and the slope between the two points on the face? My mathematical knowledge is exhausted here.

As a rule, the slope of a line is the tangent of the angle that line is making with the x axis; you can only add or subtract angles; if you really have to combine slopes you have to use the trigonometric addition formulas, eqs. (5), (6) - in your code slope12 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) then slope = (slope12 - origin_slope)/(1 + slope12 * origin_slope).

Now, your formula for origin_slope doesn't make sense, you are also dividing by zero; you probably just want to divide y9/x9 to get the slope of the line from 8 to 9 - but it's unclear if the direction from 8 to 9 has anything to do with the rotation of the system centered at 9 - that would require the point 8 to be on the x axis of the coordinates centered at 9. Please try to post a drawing that includes all the points 1, 2, 8 and 9 indicating which is which and which are the x and y axes of the coordinate systems. Here's a possible interpretation.

@kikon https://ibb.co/JkjvG2N origin_slope = (origin_point_no_9["y"] - origin_point_no_8["y"]) / (origin_point_no_9["x"] - origin_point_no_8["x"]), point12_slope = (point2["y"] - point1["y"]) / (point2["x"] - point1["x"]), return math.degrees(math.atan((point12_slope - origin_slope) / (1 + point12_slope * origin_slope)))
